# problem referencing JPA

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, orm

I have to use a jpa project on one of my projects, but I'm having this error once I create an entitymanager and call persistencecontect in my sessionbean:

```
@Stateless
public class Biblio implements BiblioLocal {
 @PersistenceContext(unitName="BiblioJPA")
 private EntityManager em;
    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public Biblio() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

 @Override
 public String succes() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return " beta";
 }
 public void toevoegenBoek(){
  Boeken boek = new Boeken();
  boek.setTitel("harry P.");
  boek.setAuteur("rowling");
  em.persist(boek);
 }

}
```

My servlet (which calls a method from this sessionbean) won't load anymore and gives me this very long error of which i don't understand anything. Any ideas? (without the entitymanager and persistencecontext my servlet does load, but then i'm not able to call any functions related to the jpa!)

Thanks!

The error i get when running the servlet:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class servlets.BiblioServlet
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to inject jndi dependency: env/servlets.BiblioServlet/biblio into property servlets.BiblioServlet.biblio: BiblioEAR not bound
    org.jboss.injection.JndiPropertyInjector.lookup(JndiPropertyInjector.java:82)
    org.jboss.injection.JndiPropertyInjector.inject(JndiPropertyInjector.java:99)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.processInjectors(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:366)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:271)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:265)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:256)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

javax.naming.NamingException: Could not dereference object [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: BiblioEAR not bound]
    org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.resolveLink(NamingContext.java:1352)
    org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)
    org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
    org.jboss.ejb3.JndiUtil.lookup(JndiUtil.java:44)
    org.jboss.injection.JndiPropertyInjector.lookup(JndiPropertyInjector.java:75)
    org.jboss.injection.JndiPropertyInjector.inject(JndiPropertyInjector.java:99)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.processInjectors(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:366)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:271)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:265)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:256)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: BiblioEAR not bound
    org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771)
    org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779)
    org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785)
    org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:396)
    org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:726)
    org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
    javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.resolveLink(NamingContext.java:1346)
    org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)
    org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
    org.jboss.ejb3.JndiUtil.lookup(JndiUtil.java:44)
    org.jboss.injection.JndiPropertyInjector.lookup(JndiPropertyInjector.java:75)
    org.jboss.injection.JndiPropertyInjector.inject(JndiPropertyInjector.java:99)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.processInjectors(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:366)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:271)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:265)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:256)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The error in my console (in eclipse)

```
DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=BiblioEAR.ear,jar=BiblioEJB.jar,name=Biblio,service=EJB3" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=BiblioEAR.ear,jar=BiblioEJB.jar,name=Biblio,service=EJB3>" (should be in state "Described", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=BiblioEAR.ear/BiblioJPA.jar#BiblioJPA' **")
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=BiblioEAR.ear,jar=BiblioEJB.jar,name=Biblio,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=BiblioEAR.ear,jar=BiblioEJB.jar,name=Biblio,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Configured", but is actually in state "PreInstall")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "persistence.unit:unitName=BiblioEAR.ear/BiblioJPA.jar#BiblioJPA" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'entity-mappings' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.
  Deployment "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:ear=BiblioEAR.ear,jar=BiblioEJB.jar,name=Biblio,service=EJB3>" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'persistence.unit:unitName=BiblioEAR.ear/BiblioJPA.jar#BiblioJPA' **
```

Edit:

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="BiblioJPA" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlDSAlfa</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

mysql-ds.xml

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>MySqlDSAlfa</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/database</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>root</user-name>
    <password></password>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
    <metadata>
       <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded to Eclipse galileo and it started working, I don't know what exactly the problem was, but that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like a JDNI lookup problem ("JPA is not able to lookup the datasource").

Could you please show your `persistence.xml` and your `xxx-ds.xml` configuration files.

---

Ok, now, this error looks weird (from the console output):

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'entity-mappings' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.

It seems you are using Object/relational Mapping Files and I'm afraid you're facing [HHH-5310](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5310) which is currently not fixed. Can you do without Object/relational Mapping Files?

Comment: Hey, I feel really stupid but seems you were right and I had a typo in my database name in my mysql-ds.xml file. (it's fixed now, name is indeed "database") However it still isn't working so I'm updating my error message and also adding the xml files. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Sled: You're welcome. But did you actually update the error message?

Comment: Hey, yea I did (it's the error I'm currently getting and "JPA is not able to lookup the datasource" is gone). I also added the console error..

Comment: I can't do it without ORM, this is the way I should be making my exercices on an exam. Strange thing is I've gotten this to work before, and I'm following the exact steps from this lesson/tutorial that's written by the lecturer. I'm also using the exact same version of JBoss.

Comment: Hey, any idea what this error could mean? DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "persistence.unit:unitName=BibliotheekEAR.ear/BibliotheekJPA.jar#BibliotheekJPA" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.RuntimeException: Specification violation [EJB3 JPA 6.2.1.2] - You have not defined a jta-data-source for a JTA enabled persistence context named: BibliotheekJPA
I'm trying again on my old desktop with an older eclipse version where it used to work on..

Answer (score -1):

http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5310

Comment: Welcome on SO. While this is a correct manner to use hyperlinks to other website, you should at least include the solution found there (in less details if you wish) and some details about the website (what it is about, in which post or comment the solution is etc.) You can use the edit link below your post to modify it and add more information when needed. I also suggest you to have a look at our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq - Good luck!